# Calculation of Containing Box's Height and Collapsing Margins

Tags: html, css, margin

When a Containing Box's top `margin` collapses with its first child's top `margin`, how to calculate the `height` of the containing box (`div` in the example)?

Take this simple example:

```css
div {
  margin: 40px 0 25px 0;
  background: yellowgreen;
  /*   border:1px solid black; */
}
p {
  margin: 20px 0 20px 0;
  background: lightgreen;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>Paragraph content</p>
</div>
```

The `p` is margins collapse with `div`, so we do not see `div`'s background color. Adding a `border` to `div` can stop margin collapse.

However, Because `p`'s `margin` is also of `div`'s `margin` ,which means `div` no longer contains the `p` entirely. This is counter-inituive.

I browsed through [Calculating heights and margins](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#Computing_heights_and_margins#normal-block) specification, and [Collapsing margins](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/box.html#collapsing-margins) and can not find how to calculate the `height` of `div`. Because you can not determine the `height` of `p`.

Comment: It is very unclear what you ask. What do you mean with _how to calculate the height of the containing box_?

Comment: @LGSon yup, and OP got to stop editing the values otherwise the answer get broken :/

Comment: @LGSon  how to calculate the height of the `div`

Comment: It is very well described here what's going on: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Box_Model/Mastering_margin_collapsing

Comment: @dippas I think your answer was good, so undelete it and add the link in my above comment for the collapse margin descripton. Also a note about when font size / line height is not set, the browsers default is used, which can give different output/size of div in this case

Comment: So the heights depend on which margins collapse. You know that. Once you've resolved those margins, and the heights of the contained in-flow boxes, you've got the calculated height. What don't you get?

Comment: @LGSon I undeleted my answer adding what you said, thanks :)

Comment: @LGSon Why div's height is not p's height + p's margins?

Comment: You need to know the height of the content and padding as well as any border to calculate the height of the container.

Comment: @J.Joe If you read the link provided in dippas answer, [Mastering margin collapsing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Box_Model/Mastering_margin_collapsing), you will find why

Answer (score 1):

In this case `div` will have the same `height` as `p` due to [collapsing margins](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/box.html#collapsing-margins) (apart from `padding`)

You know the `p`s `height` by calculating the `font-size` * `line-height`, which in your case will be :

`font-size: 16px` * `line-height:1.25` = `20px`

So,

- `p` have `height:20px`
- `div`, due to `p` having an extra `10px` of `padding` it  will make
  it the `height:40px`

```css
body {
  margin: 0
}
div {
  margin: 40px 0 25px;
  background: red;
  /*   border:1px solid black; */
}
p {
  margin: 20px 0;
  background: lightgreen;
  padding: 10px
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>Paragraph content</p>
</div>
```

**See:**

- [Mastering margin collapsing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Box_Model/Mastering_margin_collapsing)
- [What You Should Know About Collapsing Margins](https://css-tricks.com/what-you-should-know-about-collapsing-margins/)

**Note:**(By @LGSon)

> *when `font-size` / `line-height` is not set, the browsers default is used, which can give different output/size of `div` in this case*

Comment: "In this case div will have the same height as p" I can not find any specification on this. I use DevTool to inspect and they do have the same height.

Comment: Why `div`'s height is not `p`'s height + margins?

Comment: because the margin is being collapsed